# MVC Angular avoid manual serialize on CRUD operation

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

*Scenario:* MVC project from web that I customised, Angular on client that serialize scope data from Model, and when I want to do CRUD operations, I'm using temp dummy model and writing to it (for saving users' pre-change on update cancelation).

*Target:* not to use dummy object (that require me to create manual serialization).

Is there an elegant way to do it?

Code:

**View**

```
<div ng-app="demoModule" id="body">
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <h2>AngularJS CRUD Operations with MVC5 WebAPI</h2>

    <h3>List of Products</h3>

    <table ng-cloak>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="items in productsData">
                <td hidden="hidden">{{items.Id}}</td>
                <td>
                <span ng-show="!items.EditMode">{{items.Name}}</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-show="items.EditMode" data-ng-model="Product.Name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-show="!items.EditMode">{{items.Category}}</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-show="items.EditMode" data-ng-model="Product.Category" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-show="!items.EditMode">{{items.Price | currency:'&#8377;':2}}</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-show="items.EditMode" data-ng-model="Product.Price" />
                </td>

                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @*<button ng-show="!user.EditMode" ng-model="$scope.Product" ng-click="edit(productsData[$index])">Edit</button>*@
                    <button ng-show="!items.EditMode" ng-model="$scope.Product" ng-click="edit($index)">Edit</button>
                    <button ng-show="items.EditMode" ng-model="$scope.Product" data-ng-click="update()">Update</button>
                    <button ng-show="items.EditMode" ng-model="$scope.Product" data-ng-click="cancel($index)">Cancel</button>
                    <button ng-show="!items.EditMode" ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total :</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><label ng-bind="total() | currency:'&#8377;':2"></label></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br />
    <div style="border-top: solid 2px #282828; width: 430px; height: 10px"> </div>
```

**Angular:**

```
// Defining angularjs module
var app = angular.module('demoModule', []);

// Defining angularjs Controller and injecting ProductsService
app.controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ProductsService) {

$scope.productsData = null;
// Fetching records from the factory created at the bottom of the script file
ProductsService.GetAllRecords().then(function (d) {
    $scope.productsData = d.data; // Success
    angular.forEach($scope.productsData, function (obj) {
        obj["EditMode"] = false;
    })
    console.log($scope.productsData);
}, function () {
    alert('Error Occured !!!'); // Failed
});

// Calculate Total of Price After Initialization
$scope.total = function () {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.productsData, function (item) {
        total += item.Price;
    })
    return total;
}

//Here: this i want to avoid following manual serialization
$scope.Product = {
    Id: '',
    Name: '',
    Price: '',
    Category: ''
};

// Reset product details
$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.Product.Id = '';
    $scope.Product.Name = '';
    $scope.Product.Price = '';
    $scope.Product.Category = '';
    //$scope.Product.EditMode = false;
}

//Add New Item
$scope.save = function () {
    if ($scope.Product.Name != "" &&
   $scope.Product.Price != "" && $scope.Product.Category != "") {

        // or you can call Http request using $http
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/Product/PostProduct/',
            data: $scope.Product
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            $scope.productsData.push(response.data);
            $scope.clear();
            alert("Product Added Successfully !!!");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
        });
    }
    else {
        alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
    }
};

// Edit product details
$scope.edit = function (index) {
    var data = $scope.productsData[index];
    $scope.Product = { Id: data.Id, Name: data.Name, Price: data.Price, Category: data.Category, EditMode: !data.EditMode };
    $scope.productsData[index].EditMode = !$scope.productsData[index].EditMode;
    console.log($scope.productsData);
        //console.log($scope.Product);
}

// Cancel product details
$scope.cancel = function (index) {
    $scope.productsData[index].EditMode = !$scope.productsData[index].EditMode;
    $scope.clear();
    console.log($scope.Product);
}

// Update product details
$scope.update = function () {
    if ($scope.Product.Name != "" &&
   $scope.Product.Price != "" && $scope.Product.Category != "") {
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'api/Product/PutProduct/' + $scope.Product.Id,
            data: $scope.Product
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.productsData = response.data;
            $scope.clear();
            alert("Product Updated Successfully !!!");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
        });
    }
    else {
        alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
    }
};

// Delete product details
$scope.delete = function (index) {
    $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'api/Product/DeleteProduct/' + $scope.productsData[index].Id,
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.productsData.splice(index, 1);
        alert("Product Deleted Successfully !!!");
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
    });
};

});


app.factory('ProductsService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetAllRecords = function () {
        return $http.get('api/Product/GetAllProducts');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

Comment: Where is the "manual serialization" you talking about?

Comment: @lin i comment "//Here: this i want to avoid following manual serialization"